# Getting CSS from parent on an iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I am using a phpbb3 forum with a bbcode to insert an iframe. I want to use the css from the forum for the iframe. I tried some code I found here but it isn't working. I might be doing something wrong but I'd love to get this working, especially since users can change the forum css. The forum is: botdls.prophbb.com and the iframe is the "shoutbox" at the top. Thanks.  Here is the code I used from this site which I found from google.

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
            cssLink.href = "pFstylesEditor.css"; 
            cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
            cssLink .type = "text/css"; 

            //Instead of this
            //frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
            //Do this

            var doc=document.getElementById("edit").contentWindow.document 

            ///If you are doing any dynamic writing do that first
            doc.open;
            doc.write(myData);
            doc.close();

            //Then append child
            doc.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Comment: What's in "myData"? What does Firebug show you before/after the code runs?

Comment: I don't think the dynamic writing section is doing anything.  I can probably just take it out.  It's a CFM page that I'm loading into the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted one problem right away.  You're creating an element in the parent document and trying to append it to the child document - this won't work.  You need to create the element using the child frame's document instead:

```
var doc=document.getElementById("edit").contentWindow.document;

var cssLink = doc.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "pFstylesEditor.css";  
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";  
cssLink.type = "text/css";  

///If you are doing any dynamic writing do that first 
doc.open();        // <-- you also missed the parenthesis here
doc.write(myData); 
doc.close(); 

//Then append child 
doc.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Also, `open` is a method and you missed off the parenthesis (`open()`).

Comment: I just pulled this off another post here.  How can I figure out the ElementID?  Firebug lists them all separately.  I tried what I thought the element id is but I just want to make sure that's not my mistake.  Also, pFstylesEditor.css should be changed to the actual link of the css stylesheet or is that a naming convention like with prototype or jQuery?